# How to reset the focus on the button in the middle of control row Android-tv?

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback

The ControlsFragment extends VideoFragment() in which extends PlaybackFragment(). I am using leanback v27.0.2. The problem is once i change the focus from the middle to the left (Rewind button) or to the right (forward button) and the controls fragment disappear on reappear the focus doesn't reset to the middle. I want the focus to reset and appear in the middle on top of the play pause button if the focus wasn't in the middle.

Can anyone has an idea of how to fix this issue ?

Thanks :)

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. :-) [After doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: Is there any other solution compatible with leanback 27.0.2 version to reset focus of player control then decreasing version of library?? Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that i am using leanback version 27.0.2 
In this version we don't have access to the ControlBar class to use the method setDefaultFocusToMiddle. If we need to reset the focus to the middle the leanback version 23.1.1 will do the job.